# Show form on specific time

Tags: eclipse-scout

can I show form in scout on specific date/time?

For example: I have reminders in app. I want to show reminder form on specific time to user.

I know I can use timer in form, but then I need to add that "timer code" to all forms I have in app, so timer can be fired.

Is there another way to add it in one place, not to all forms?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, please check the technical guide for Eclipse Scout. In [chapter 9, JobManager](https://eclipsescout.github.io/9.0/technical-guide.html#jobmanager) you should find everything about jobs and also code examples for how to schedule a job.

For your case you must schedule a ModelJob and create a JobInput with an ExecutionTrigger that uses the `#withStartAt(Date)` method. This should work:

```
Date reminderDate = new Date();
ModelJobs.schedule(() -> {
    new ReminderForm().start();
}, ModelJobs.newInput(ClientRunContexts.copyCurrent())
        .withName("Open reminder form")
        .withExecutionTrigger(Jobs.newExecutionTrigger()
                .withStartAt(reminderDate))
        .withExceptionHandling(new ExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Throwable t) {
                System.err.println(t);
            }
        }, true));
```

Maybe you should also check out the "desktop notification" concept, which allows to notify users with a less intrusive widget than a form. You'll find an example [here](https://scout.bsi-software.com/widgets/?dl=widget-desktop), click on the "Show notification" button.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this

Comment: Hi, I added this, but code in not executed...Not stopping on breakpoint in debug.

Comment: I assume you have adjusted the dummy code in my example above and you do not simply make a new Date() but instead create a Date instance for the exact date/time (in the future) when the scheduled Job should run?

Comment: Yes, i create date with 2 min in future, but whole code does not stop on breakpoint. Do I need to register jobs in platform listener?

Comment: From where exactly do you call the schedule() method? Is the schedule() method called at all? And no, you don't need a platform listener to schedule jobs. You could put the code in the execInit() method of your Desktop class, for instance. But any other place will do, as long as you're in the Scout model job.

Comment: I will try at Desktop.java. Thanks